# Prevent Qt Widget from inheriting parent applications style

Tags: pyqt, pyside

When writing a Qt plug-in for a third-party application that is already using Qt, the style of my widgets and the font are not honored, and instead aspects of the third party parent application leak into my widgets, despite explicitly styling against it. How can I force only my widgets to be in the same style that it would if I were to run gui from a OS python shell?

How the UI looks when run from system python interpreter:

[image: How the UI looks when run from system python interpreter]

How the UI looks when run from the third-party application:

[image: How the UI looks when run from the third-party application]

```
from qtpy import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('This is a Test!')
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.h_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.h_layout)
        self.h_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.icon_left = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.icon_left.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('bell.png'))
        self.line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit.setPlaceholderText('Type something here')

        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.icon_left)
        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)

# this line and the sys.exit lines are commented when running the gui in third party applications

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = Dialog(parent=parent)
fdb = QtGui.QFontDatabase()
fdb.addApplicationFont('Kablammo-Regular.ttf')
font = QtGui.QFont('Kablammo')
font.setPointSize(11)
widget.setFont(font)
widget.setStyleSheet("""
    QLineEdit{
        border: 2px solid red;
        border-radius: 8px;
    }
""")

widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried explicitly setting the font and stylesheets on the widget instead of the QApplication but it still gets overriden by the parent application.

I am expecting my UI to look like the first image no matter where it is run

Comment: Note that the code you're providing is not valid for your purposes: if the widget (or, better, the script) is being imported and added to the host application, it should ***not*** have any of the lines starting from `import sys`; if you're properly using the known `if __name__ == '__main__':` check, then your code is not a valid [mre] (and you should provide one instead), otherwise anything you do there is completely irrelevant, since the host application is probably ignoring the *wrong* attempt to create a further QApplication, and it just creates the new widget from the class.

Comment: @musicamante When running the code in the third party application I comment out the lines for creating the `QApplication`, `import sys`, and `sys.exit(app.exec_())`. Since you don't have access to my presumed third party application, I have to include these lines so that you can reproduce the application.

Comment: The problem is that the very fact that the issues happens when the widget is embedded completely nullifies the purpose of those lines: while they may be (theoretically) useful to see the result outside the host application, the problem remains: anything you do there is completely irrelevant when the custom class is embedded elsewhere: the `addApplicationFont()` and `setFont()` calls and even the `setStyleSheet()` one. If you don't do something similar **within** the class that's being actually being added to the host application, then they are worthless.

Comment: The third party application has a python interpreter built in. I’m simply running this code in the interpreter. So those lines are needed and not ignored.

Comment: That's exactly the point. You're not supposed to use it like that by creating a *further* QApplication, instead you should load the existing QApplication instance (or, in this case, the SDApplication) and work with that.